# scrollview not working if translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, scrollview

I have some issues using translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.
I am creating a scrollview where you can swipe to the left or right. Every time you get a another image. But for some reason I can't swipe if translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false.

This is with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false (in this case, I can't swipe left or right)

[image]

But if I set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true it look like this and I can swipe to the left and right. The problem is, that the layout is messed up.

[image]

My code:

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        return scrollView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
scrollView.frame = contentView.frame
        contentView.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}

var frame = CGRect.zero
    func viewTutorial() {
        for i in 0..<arrayOfTutorilImages.count {
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width  * CGFloat((i))
            frame.size = scrollView.frame.size

            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfTutorilImages[i])
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.backgroundColor = .red
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)


            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(arrayOfTutorilImages.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

extension TutorialViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: is content view created from an Outlet?

Comment: yes, this is from an outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add constraints probably , You can try

```
class TutorialViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
            let scrollView = UIScrollView()
            scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
            scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
            scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
            return scrollView
        }()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad() 
            contentView.addSubview(scrollView)

            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            viewTutorial()
    }


        func viewTutorial() {
            var con:UIView = scrollView
            for i in 0..<arrayOfTutorilImages.count {

                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfTutorilImages[i])
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                imageView.backgroundColor = .red
                imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

                if con == scrollView {
                     imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: con.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                }
                else {
                     imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: con.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                }

                imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

                if i == arrayOfTutorilImages.count - 1 {
                    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

                }
                imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
              imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                con = imageView


            }

            scrollView.delegate = self
        }
}

extension TutorialViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
     func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width

     }
 }
```

> Don't set frames when using constrraints

Comment: the page controls is working, but the image is way to big

Comment: added `imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true` in edit try again

Comment: the image is now the right size. But there is still another problem. There is a big space above and underneath the image.

Comment: ok I edited a heightAnchor to it and set the constraint equalTo: contentView

Answer (score 0):

Add Scrollview frame when create

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame:.zero)
    //other properties
    return scrollView
}()
```

Comment: same problem is still there after editing  property

Comment: why are you using this setup instead of UIcollectionView? Is there any requirement?

Comment: This is from a tutorial, and I extend it a little it.

Answer (score 0):

ImageView constraints same as for ScrollView.
That is the reason why you can't swipe, because all your images have the same constraints, and they are located one over another.
You should do smth like:

```swift
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
imageView.frame.size = contentView.frame.size
imageView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: imageIndex * contentView.frame.size.width, y: 0.0)
```

Comment: Error: CGRect has no member size

Comment: Hmm... CGRect has size property, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect